# How can I use emacs to run xquery code on a Marklogic database?

Tags: emacs, xquery, marklogic

Instead of having to switch between editing files in emacs and doing little tests in the Marklogic query console, I'd really like to be able to open a buffer, write a little XQuery, then run it against a Marklogic server I've got running on a virtual machine.  In effect, I suppose the perfect solution would result in something similar to the scratch buffer, where you write some elisp, then hit C-j to execute it.

Comment: Why not just run your client program in an interactive shell within Emacs?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  The Marklogic server is running on a virtual machine, and the query console is a web front-end to some communication channel that runs arbitrary XQuery code on the associated database.  What I want to do is do those queries from within emacs.  I don't have a client program, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I've never used MarkLogic, but do they have existing command-line tools or maybe an API over HTTP? Wrapping calls to either from Emacs should be fairly easy.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly I just move my code into libraries, and import those libraries from cq. But you could write elisp that sends your query via HTTP to the cq or QueryConsole `eval.xqy` module, as an HTTP POST.

You could also use a textarea emacs interface for your browser, so that you can use cq via emacs.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ljobjlafonikaiipfkggjbhkghgicgoh

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/its-all-text/

https://github.com/marklogic/cq

Comment: It seems like doing a POST to eval.xqy would be the easiest option.

Answer (score 1):

Calling eval.xqy over HTTP as suggested by @mblakele is probably easiest. But if you want tighter integration, there is the XCC library (Java/.Net; http://developer.marklogic.com/products/xcc/5.0 ), and also the slightly older libmlcc library ( http://robbertbroersma.nl/blog/a-blog.html ). Perhaps those are useful to you..

Comment: I think I'm going to give the eval option a go, but it looks as though I'm going to have to do some configuration on the Marklogic side, so it seems to be a case of two steps forward, three steps back.

Comment: You may be able to avoid extra configuration if you have MarkLogic 5. That version includes query console, which includes an `eval.xqy`. It's at `Apps/qconsole/endpoints/eval.xqy` under your MarkLogic install directory, which means that it's available by default: eg http://localhost:8000/qconsole/endpoints/eval.xqy